# How to use the var declaration to new public class

Tags: c#

public class a:

```
public class a: b
{
   ...
}
```

and b is:

```
public abstract class b
{
   ...
}
```

I want to use the class a in my C# application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   ...

   private void my_function(...)
   {
       var c = new a();
   }
}
```

But I got the exception when my_function run

```
 var c = new a(),
```

and exception message is

```
 System.TypeInitializationException
```

How to correct declare and fix this exception?

Comment: That's the exception type. What is the exception message?

Comment: Provide the full code. The problem is not with `var`.

Comment: The posted code couldn't possibly result in that kind of exception. You're missing information.

Comment: Could you please post the code of class `a`? Thanks. I suspect that you may have defined a constructor with parameters there and you try to use a parameterless constructor, which would result in an error.

Comment: @Christos Well, no, that'd result in a compiler error, wouldn't it?

Comment: @J.Steen yup, you are correct. But certainly something goes wrong that we can't see in the posted code.

Comment: A friendly tip on using Stack Overflow (or any SE site) to ask questions: hang around when you've asked your question. Most of the attention will come within the first few minutes and you need to be on your toes to answer comments and post updates.

Comment: Hi all, I try to modify the example code into my funciton, so forgive me no paste the full code and confuse the exception type and exception message. I originally thought it was a syntax error, but now i certain problem is not with var, I fount the 'a class' caused the error occurred. it was Initialization error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have created same scenario as per your question in console application. On my side it is working fine. Please see my code :

```
 public abstract class TestBaseClass
{
    public void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base method");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : TestBaseClass
{
    public void testDerived()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived method");
    }
}
```

Main Method :

```
 public class BaseClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var c = new DerivedClass();
    }
}
```

[image]
It is working fine on my end. Is this useful for you to make changes in your code according to this process?

Comment: This code is very helpful for me, and my code it is working when fix the 'a class' error Initialization.

Comment: Glad to hear that issue has been resolved. We are here to help, not to make problem more complicated. Hope i will  be here to solve more issues..